# How to infer probability using frequency table?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a frequency table of 3x3 representing how many users of type A, B, C have done actions 1, 2, 3 (for example, Cell [1,1]=80 Users of Type A have done action 1)

How can I compute the probability that a user belongs to each type given the actions they've done? (for example if a new user has done actions 1 & 3 what is the most probable type they belong to?)

How is this back inference method called?

Comment: Multinomial regression with the type as outcome and the actions as predictors could give you some sense what the probability of being a certain type is. I do not know whether it is the most accurate compared to other techniques such as clustering. Additionally, I'd wonder whether you have the 'true' distribution of actions defining the types. Do you estimate these from your data or do you know that for example type A users perform have a 60% probability to perform action 1, 0% to perform action 2, and 10% to perform action 3?

Comment: I estimate these from my data, but I have thousands of samples per cell so guessing it should estimate the overall population well? (population being users who are using the product)

Comment: I thought there should be a way to do this via bayes rule/conditional probability - but can't find the right way to calculate for multiple conditions. Also wondering how to account if some of the actions are not independent? just to remove 'duplicates'?

Comment: Maybe you could add these initial ideas to your question and show where you get stuck. You could state you do not necessarily want to use these methods, but that the probability of being a certain type is the goal. Some sample of your data could also give others here some idea what the possibilities are. AFAIK, multinomial regression would be a good place to start, but some (other) kind of supervised (because you know the types) learner might also apply (but that's not my cup of tea).